# Intent filter's pathPattern not working as expected

Tags: android, intentfilter

I'm trying to support `.vyb` files in my application (from mail) and added this intent filter for that.

```
<data
     android:mimeType="application/octet-stream"
     android:pathPattern=".*\\.vyb"
     android:scheme="content" />
```

But its also opening the `.mobi` files. File's full name is something like `mybook.lc.mobi`.

I'm not sure what's the problem here, can someone help me understand the problem here?

Comment: Few `content` scheme `Uri` values will have a file extension. And, overall, for local content, `pathPattern` has not been useful in the past few years because of the prevalence of `content` scheme `Uri` values.

Comment: @CommonsWare Is their any possible workaround for this?

Comment: Not really. You cannot force the rest of the world's developers to change their apps, such that all `content` `Uri` values end with a file extension. This is not significantly different than with the Web -- for example, this Web page's URL does not have a file extension.

Comment: This is a truly infuriating limitation. If we really expect the idea of "file types" to be governed by the `mimeType`, then the `mimeType` should become intrinsic to the file itself (i.e. at the filesystem level, not merely in the _transport layer_ when exchanging the file between apps).

And while I appreciate @CommonsWare 's comment, their comparison to "this web page's URL" isn't exactly accurate, since this URL can be used as part of a path filter, whereas the path filter for a `content` scheme simply... doesn't work at all.